# SQL Oracle: Trying to pull a count with AND operators, New and needs experienced eyes

Tags: sql, oracle, data-science

I am new to SQL and have had pretty good luck figuring things out thus far but I am missing something in this query:

The question is how to return a distinct count from two columns using another column and the criteria if the value is greater than 0.

I have tried IF and AND operators (My current query returns a 0 not an error, and it works when only using one .shp criteria)

```
select count (distinct ti.TO_ADDRESS)
from ti
where ti.input_id = 'xxx_029_01z_c_zzzzbab_ecrm.shp'

and ti.input_id = 'xxx_030_01z_c_zzzzbab_ecrm.shp'

and ti.OPENED>0;
```

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Could you show us what you want your output to look like?

Comment: I would like a number. A count if both .shp files have have a greater value than zero in the opened column.

Comment: `ti.input_id = 'xxx_029_01z_c_zzzzbab_ecrm.shp' and ti.input_id = 'xxx_030_01z_c_zzzzbab_ecrm.shp'` is always false. A field cannot have two values at once. That query thus returns nothing. Did you mean `OR`?

Comment: Thinking about it, I think it would be AND or IF somehow.

Comment: ID_INPUT, TO_ADDRESS, and OPENED are all column headers. So am asking the database based on the TO_ADDRESS did a person with different ID_INPUT have a greater than zero value in OPENED.

Comment: Have a clean question title,only upto the point. This  forum is not  a consultancy firm for  you to decide who needs to solve your  problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select ti.TO_ADDRESS
      from ti
      where ti.input_id in ('xxx_029_01z_c_zzzzbab_ecrm.shp', 'xxx_030_01z_c_zzzzbab_ecrm.shp') and
            ti.OPENED > 0
      group by ti.TO_ADDRESS
      having count(distinct ti.input_id) = 2  -- has both of them
     ) ti;
```

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you so much for helping me expand my understanding of how to query. That worked. You just saved me countless hours of excel work.